# Loading WebView in background

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiwebview, background, loading

I have a tab bar application with 6 view controllers.
The third tab is a view controller that loads google form on a WebView.
The problem is that the webview start loading just when i move to the view controller of the webview, but i want the webview to load in background before i'm moving to its view controller, right after the app starts. i don't want the user waiting for the form to load.
This is my webview code:

```
-(void)webViewDisplay
{
    CGSize webScreen;
    webScreen = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame].size;
    self.formWebView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
    self.formWebView.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);

    formWebView.inputView.hidden = YES;

    [self.view addSubview: self.formWebView];

    [self.formWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:
                                                                [NSString stringWithFormat:(NSString *)@"%@", @"https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/viewform?formkey=dHphcHBIaVQ5TFh1b2JOQWItd0JCTkE6MQ"]]]];
    formWebView.scrollView.bounces = NO;
}
```

What is the best way to do that?
Thanks for the help...

Answer (score 0):

Managed to find the way :)
In my AppDelegate i did:

```
ThirdViewController *thirdVC = [[ThirdViewController alloc] init];  
[thirdVC performSelector:@selector(webViewDisplay) withObject:nil];
```

Works great.
Thanks anyway...